# Systemd service (python loop -> ffmpeg stream)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, stream, debian, systemd

I am currently running a stream with **ffmpeg**, through **icecast2** through a **python** snippet (*Fig1*).  I have created a **systemd** service to run said **python** script on boot (*Fig2*) and use a custom target (*Fig3*) to make sure it loads once every other service is loaded, mostly for **icecast2**.

I've conducted multiple tests, and the stream works fine if launched either from the python code or if I restart the service attached to it.

My problem is, on a (re)boot of the system, the service runs for approximately 15 seconds, then the stream dies.  I've read so much on **python** and **systemd**, but I can't for the life of me figure out where the problem lies.  I've tried changing my **python** code, the unit load order and anything else I found online that could help, but found nothing.

*Fig1* (dxstream.py)

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess

def start():
    return subprocess.Popen(r’ffpmeg -re -f alsa -ac2 -i hw:1,0 -acodec mp3 -ab 320k -f mp3 icecast://sourcehackme@localhost:8000/stream', shell=True)

testProcess = start()

while True:

    res = testProcess.poll()
    if res is not None:
        testProcess = start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

*Fig2* (dxstream.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=ffmpeg stream starter
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
Execstart=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/dxstream.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=custom.target
```

*Fig3* (custom.target)

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Target
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set reporting to ON for the ffmpeg stream, as well as track the boot process of the unit and it seems it was prematurely creating a link to IceCast while IceCast was still initializing. I added a 30-second delay to the script itself for the first boot, and it works properly now.

Closing this topic!